# Bash's history behavior when using ! and ! :p for old commands changed

Tags: bash, command-history, history-expansion

Suddenly my bash history behavior changed. When I'm either calling an old command using !num (where num is the number of the commmand as seen in history) or displaying the command (without running it) using !num:p, the command disappears from my history.

This can be seen here:

```
[f@meshtretch 19.8G  ~ ] $ history 
    1  su
    2  exit
    3  whoami
    4  uptime 
    5  uname -a
    6  history 

[f@meshtretch 19.8G  ~ ] $ !3:p
whoami

[f@meshtretch 19.8G  ~ ] $ history 
    1  su
    2  exit
    3  uptime 
    4  uname -a
    5  whoami
    6  history
```

I'm expecting the "whoami" command to still show at number 3 (and not just at 5) but it disappeared. It's the same behavior for all the users on my system.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out I did the following in my .bashrc:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups:erasedups
```

when I meant to do:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
```

But somehow I forgot I made the change because I hadn't used the ! an !...:p functionalities in a while. Then I copied the *.bashrc* to my various users account.